# Creating Object from variable name

Tags: php, string, class

How do i create my class object in single line from a variable:

```
$strClassName = 'CMSUsers';
$strModelName = $strClassName.'Model';
$strModelObj = new $strModelName();
```

The above code successfully creates my CMSUsersModel class object but when i try:

```
$strClassName = 'CMSUsers';
$strModelObj = new $strClassName.'Model'();
```

it pops error.... saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in
```

Comment: Why do need this 'optimization'?

Comment: You cannot do string concatenation while object instantiation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiate new object from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964113/instantiate-new-object-from-variable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not use string concatenation while creating objects.

if you use

```
class aa{}

$str = 'a';
$a = new $str.'a';   // Fatal error : class a not found



class aa{}

$str = 'a';
$a = new $str.$str; // Fatal error : class a not found
```

So You should use

```
$strModelName = $strClassName.'Model';
$strModelObj = new $strModelName();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure because I'm not up to date with classes and PHP, but I think `$strModelName` is the class definition, thus I think you have to use one two lines or write something like this:

```
$strModelName = 'CMSUsers'.'Model'; $strModelObj = new $strModelName();
```

Answer (score 0):

> As of PHP 8.0.0, using `new` with arbitrary expressions is supported.
> This allows more complex instantiation if the expression produces a
> string. ([Example #4 Creating an instance using an arbitrary expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-197))

However, the expression must be wrapped in parentheses. The `new` operator is of higher precedence than string concatenation `.` (see [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)), so `$strModelObj = new $strClassName.'Model'();` means `$strModelObj = (new $strClassName).('Model'());`. The correct parenthesizing would be `$strModelObj = new ($strClassName.'Model')();`.

A minimal working example (MWE) for PHP 8:

```php
<?php
class CMSUsersModel {}
$strClassName = 'CMSUsers';
$strModelObj = new ($strClassName.'Model')();
var_dump($strModelObj);
```