# Instantiate new object from variable

Tags: php

I'm using the following class to autoload all my classes. This class extends the core class.

```
class classAutoloader extends SH_Core {

     public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));      
     }

     private function loader($class_name) {
        $class_name_plain = strtolower(str_replace("SH_", "", $class_name));
        include $class_name_plain . '.php';
     }
}
```

I instantiate that class in the `__construct()` of my core class:

```
public function __construct() {
    $autoloader = new classAutoloader();
}
```

Now I want to be able to instantiate objects in the loader class like this:

```
private function loader($class_name) {
    $class_name_plain = strtolower(str_replace("SH_", "", $class_name));
    include $class_name_plain . '.php';
    $this->$class_name_plain = new $class_name;
}
```

But I get the following error calling `$core-template` like this:

```
require 'includes/classes/core.php';
$core = new SH_Core();

if (isset($_GET['p']) && !empty($_GET['p'])) {
    $core->template->loadPage($_GET['p']);
} else {
    $core->template->loadPage(FRONTPAGE);   
}
```

The error:

> Notice: Undefined property: SH_Core::$template in /home/fabian/domains/fabianpas.nl/public_html/framework/index.php on line 8
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function loadPage() on a non-object in /home/fabian/domains/fabianpas.nl/public_html/framework/index.php on line 8

It autoloads the classes but just doesn't initiate the object because using the following code it works without any problems:

```
public function __construct() {
    $autoloader = new classAutoloader();

    $this->database = new SH_Database();
    $this->template = new SH_Template();
    $this->session = new SH_Session();
}
```

Comment: That function you are getting an error for isn't in the code you have given us. In order to help with the error we need the code causing the error.

Comment: Your error and prose refer to things not represented in the given code. Provide a _testcase_.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried:

```
$this->$class_name_plain = new $class_name();
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using:

```
private function createObjects() {
    $handle = opendir('./includes/classes/');
    if ($handle) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                $object_name = str_replace(".php", "", $file);
                if ($object_name != "core") {
                    $class_name = "SH_" . ucfirst($object_name);
                    $this->$object_name = new $class_name();
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
```